# get all the values of property in array objects

Tags: php, laravel

i have an array full of objects , in each object there is properties i wanna collect a specific property in all the object that i have and assign them to a variable.

this is the array

```js
[
  {
    "id": 23,
    "user_id": 2,
    "friend_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "user_id": 2,
    "friend_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07"
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "user_id": 2,
    "friend_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07"
  }
]
```

i wanna get the value of **friend_id**

whats the best practices to do so?
thanks.

Comment: [array_column()](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+array_column&oq=php+array_column&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.2410j0j2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: `array_column($your_array, 'friend_id')`

Comment: array_column works just with the nested arrays right ! not with nested objects

Comment: In PHP 7.0 they added objects.

Comment: If you're getting the array from JSON, you can use the optional argument to `json_decode()` to create associative arrays instead of objects.

Comment: worked fine after decode it ! thanks buddy !

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a json string, so you would need to decode it first:

```
$friends = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

The you can extract the ids with array column as suggested in comments, or a foreach loop if you are using php 5.4 or below:

```
$friend_ids = array_column($friends, 'friend_id');
//OR
$friend_ids=array();
foreach($friends as $friend)
    $friend_ids[] = $friend['friend_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array map.  What this will do is assign all the friend id's into a new array.  I'm passing an anonymous function that returns just the friend id out of the object.  For more info on `array_map`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
<?php 
$json = '[
  {
    "id": 23,
    "user_id": 2,
    "friend_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "user_id": 2,
    "friend_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07"
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "user_id": 2,
    "friend_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-23 21:00:07"
  }
]';

$jsonObject = json_decode($json);

$newArray = array_map(function($a) {
  return $a->friend_id;
}, $jsonObject);

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: this works just fine too , i guess using array_column method will be better and less hassle